# Who or what is "the crown"?

Tags: plot-explanation, judas-and-the-black-messiah

In the movie *Judas and the Black Messiah*, when the Black Panthers are playing pool in a pub while giving a speech at the same time, another group of African Americans wearing green berets approach them and force them to leave with threats.

[image]

The beret-wearing African Americans state:

> This place is under the protection of the crown.

I am wondering who or what is "the crown"?

Comment: "The crown" is often used to refer to the British monarchy, but that can't be the case here, since this film is set in America.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "the crowns". According to the [script](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Judas-And-The-Black-Messiah-Screenplay.pdf), page 5:

> A2 INSIDE - O’NEAL’S POV                         A2
>
> Five young black men cluster around a pool table in the back. Several wear green berets: the calling card of the Crowns, Chicago’s most notorious gang.

Answer (score 0):

After watching the movie a second time, I can confirm that the Crown or the Crowns is the name for a gang. Just like Black Panthers; the crowns are not related to the British royal family in any way.